# LaunchDaemons is giving error 127

Tags: ios, daemon, launchd, start-stop-daemon

i have a problem when i run  LaunchDaemons this is my .plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" 
"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>Label</key>
<string>com.startup</string>
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string>/Users/myuser/project/workspace/tomcat/run/tomcat-
   exp.sh</string>
</array>
<key>RunAtLoad</key>
<true/>
<key>WatchPaths</key>
<array>
   <string>/Users/myuser/project/workspace/tomcat/log/exp.out</string>
</array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

and this is the error am getting, i have been trying to solve this issue for hours but no suceess :(

when i checked system log this is what i found:

```
16239 Dec 28 21:36:29 myyser MRT[1481]: Error: SMJobRemove: The 
operation couldn’t be completed. (CFErrorDomainLaunchd error 2.)
16240 Dec 28 21:36:29 myuser com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] 
(com.apple.mrt[1481]): Service exited with abnormal code: 2
16241 Dec 28 21:36:29 myuser com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.mrt): 
Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seco      
nds.
```

Answer (score 3):

Your plist looks running shell script. Exit code 127 is reported when command is not found, usually $PATH is not correct or just by typo.

Other than that, your plist looks ok though I have only used OnDemand, and I haven't run script.
What I usually do to debug daemons is to run them from command line

```
# /bin/launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/mydaemon.plist
```

and see debug messages by fprintf on shell. You can redirect your stdout by adding

```
<key>StandardOutPath</key>
<string>/var/log/mylog.log</string>
```

to your .plist. Does your daemon work w/o any issue when started by command line manually ?

See [this link](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html) for exit codes of scripts of bash.

Comment: unfortunately no. i have added what my log shows. its on the question i posted please let me know if u can figure it out. i have been trying but no success

Comment: Not sure only with your log. Where do you get 127? Are you trying to run script?

Comment: yeah when i run the script manually work fine when i run it through lauchctl it does nothing

Comment: Then where do you get 127? W/o further detail, not possible to debug.

Comment: actually maybe i figure out the problem so this is how my shell script look like: so basically my when i add line to redirect shell script output to a file it doesnt really run but it gives status 0 since i guess the txt file was empty. so maybe the problem was my shell sccript

Comment: #!/bin/bash

export LOGGING_CONFIG="-Djava.util.logging.config.file=${HOME}/workspace/tomcat/conf/log.pot.props"
export CATALINA_OUT="${HOME}/workspace/tomcat/log/port.out"
export JAVA_OPTS="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xms256m -Xmx2048m -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m"
export CATALINA_BASE="${HOME}/workspace/tomcat"
export CATALINA_HOME="${HOME}"

${TOMCAT_HOME}/bin/startup.sh -config ${HOME}/workspace/tomcat/conf/server-port.xml

Comment: startup.sh at last is the only command. I would recommend to investigate it by adding echo > logfile and see where the issue is.

Comment: yeah i think u r right its startup.sh but dont know why launchctl complain abt path variables on my shell script . am puting those variables on bash_profile so they are global y cant launchctl read them?

Comment: I understand bash reads bash_profile, bash_login, etc. when started as login shell. You can easily check if your _profile is read by bash. Check bash man page.

Answer (score 0):

We also had the same problem with error 127. However in our case we tried to use a symbolic inside a plist file running a peerJs server which was causing the problem [discussed here](https://github.com/peers/peerjs-server/issues/270)

Avoid using a symbolic link inside a launch daemon file and use real path to a specific file